# There is an option in ImageMagick that automatically cut out the written part of a page?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I use ImageMagick (with Windows 10) to convert my `.pdf` in `.png`, for example:

```
convert -background white -alpha remove -density 150 "mydoc.pdf" -quality 100 "mydoc.png"
```

I'd like to know if there is an option that automatically (that is without explicitly giving the size) cut out the written part of a page.

For example, from an image like this:

[image]

get an image like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `-trim` option:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim

Simply add it to your command. You might also add the `+repage` option to reset the canvas offset:

```
convert -background white -alpha remove -density 150 -trim +repage "mydoc.pdf" -quality 100 "mydoc.png"
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, I'd never have thought it was so easy! Thank you!